# Убрать Disabled у select через jquery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.
Есть такой код

```
<select class="form-control" name="area" disabled  required>
```

При определенный действиях должно отключаться свойство disabled

```
$('select[name="area"]')[0].disabled = true;
```

Но оно почему то не отключается. Что делать?

Comment: $('select[name="area"]')[0].removeAttribute('disabled');

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select[name="area"]')[0].prop('disabled', true);
```